# IntelliJ Forward Delete Mac

Tags: macos, intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ on a Mac and am looking for a keybinding that allows me to delete the character in front of the cursor. I know it is possible with fn+DEL, but I would like to remap it to control+d as it is in other buffers on my machine.

I've looked at the keymap in preferences and cannot find a corresponding command to remap. It almost seems that they didn't account for a desire to forward delete, which surely can't be the case.

Comment: Exactly what I needed to know :D

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's an action called (unsurprisingly) Delete (Preferences | Keymap | Main Menu | Edit | Delete)

Comment: Surprisingly, however, it is not with the Backspace action. I missed it because it was in "Preferences | Keymap | Main Menu | Edit", whereas Backspace and the similar actions I'd been updating were in "Preferences | Keymap | Editor Actions".

Comment: Surprisingly, indeed.

Comment: And the related Delete to Word End is in "Preferences | Keymap | Editor Actions" as well.

Comment: Also maybe related (I use it all the time) is "Preferences | Keymap | Editor Actions -> Delete to line end" or Cut to line end (default ctrl + k).